# Read an image source from an image control

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, image-processing

I am able to set the image source of a control as follows:

```
Dim photo As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
photo.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(New Uri("Assets/Photos/image.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
Me.myImage.Source = photo
```

Now, how can I read the source url of the image that is displayed in the control? I am trying something like this:

```
Dim source as String = Me.myImage.Source.GetValue(???)
```

but I am getting errors of 'cannot be converted to system.windows.DependencyProperty'

Also, can the GetValue method give me the size of the image as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your BitmapImages like

```
Dim photo As BitmapImage =
    New BitmapImage(New Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Photos/image.jpg"))
myImage.Source = photo
```

you will later be able to get the URI back from the BitmapImage's `UriSource` property:

```
Dim bitmap As BitmapImage = myImage.Source
Dim uri As Uri = bitmap.UriSource
```

EDIT: Creating a BitmapImage as shown above is equivalent to

```
Dim photo As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
photo.UriSource = New Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Photos/image.jpg")
```

The effect is that the `UriSource` property is set, and can later be read back. Calling `BitmapImage.SetSource`, as you did in your question, will not set `UriSource`. That's why it always returned `null`.

Comment: I noticed (from your example) that by removing the Application.GetResourceStream I am now able to read the string from the UriSource. Strange. Also I am not sure how it may impact the application but so far so good. I thought that was a way to always make sure I get the path right... Thank you

Comment: That isn't strange at all. In your question you are calling `BitmapImage.SetSource`, which *does not set* the `UriSource` property. If you create a BitmapImage by its constructor with Uri parameter, this *will set* UriSource.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun! When I remove Application.GetResourceStream (using Clemens suggested solution) I can later read the Uri.Source into string, as noted above. But the image control is now not displaying the image. I need to have Image Control display the image, then later on come back to it to read the path of the image it is currently displaying; it is a slide show sort of application.

Comment: Forget that, too. You'll have to use the `ms-appx://` [Uri scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx). I've edited the answer. The image's Build Action should be set to `Content`.

Comment: Exception thrown for using Relative, so I changed to UriKind.Absolute and it passed. But even though I can get back the current uri of the image, the image control is still not displaying the image. I am now trying to read the uri before it is passed to the image control and save its value somewhere else from where I will read it when needed.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that too, and made another edit. Did you make sure to have a triple slash `///` in the `ms-appx:///` Uri to refer to the "currently running app's package"? It works for me that way in a Store App, when the Build Action of the image file is Content.

Answer (score 0):

The Image.Source here is the BitmapImage (if you didn't know you just set it to one it could be other ImageSource types as well). You can retrieve that and then check its UriSource property to get the Uri and from that the OriginalString:

```
Dim bmp As BitmapImage = myImage.Source
Dim uriSource As Uri = bmp.UriSource
Dim source As String = uriSource.OriginalString

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Source is {0}", source)
```

In a non-contrived example you'll probably want to put this in a try/catch block or add other checks to handle the cases where the myImage.Source isn't a BitmapImage or where the BitmapImage isn't loaded from a URI.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. But I am getting empty string in all cases (.bmp, .jpg, .png)... I will be loading all of them from a URI.

Comment: Empty string for UriSource means the BitmapImage wasn't loaded from a URI

Comment: I think my problem is related to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/d1cc972d-f4fc-4a23-8e23-4a03219dc1f3/get-image-file-name-from-photochoosertask). I gave up since I realise there is no way/sense of getting the photos names without ending up with a ridiculous application!